# find() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a bunch of `li` elements dynamically

```
$.each(data.attributes.listingImages, function (i, obj){
if(i == 1){
   $('#js-carousel-menu').append('<li media class="active"><a media-frame><img class="js-carousel-item" src=" '+obj.thumbnail+ ' " /></a></li>' );
 }else{
   $('#js-carousel-menu').append('<li media><a media-frame><img class="js-carousel-item" src=" '+obj.thumbnail+ ' " /></a></li>' );
}
```

then when i try search for the 'active' `li` its not finding it

```
$gallery = $(this.el).find('#js-carousel-menu');
var _this = $gallery.find('li.active');
```

however if i trace out `$gallery` it give me :

```
<ul>
 <li media>...</li>
 <li media class="active">...</li>
 <li media>...</li>
 ...
 <li media>...</li>
</ul>
```

am i missing something? thanks

Comment: Doing .find() with an id as a selector is silliness. You should just use $('#js-carousel-menu').find('li.active') as you can only legally have one unique id on a page anyway.

Also, at what point are you executing the code? Is the .active class added before or after you run .find('li.active')

Comment: Is the use of the media attribute without a value valid?

Comment: @Adam ive tried that, and i still get nothing...i run a function "buildGallery" which builds out the li elements, then right after that i call the find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `#js-carousel-menu` is an ID, you shouldn't need to find it, you can just select it directly. Check to see of the selector was successful.

```
alert($(this.el).find('#js-carousel-menu').length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because an ID must be unique, `$(this.el).find('#js-carousel-menu');` is useless (and potentially the reason of your problem): there can be only one `#js-carousel-menu`.

So, try with:

```
var _this = $('#js-carousel-menu').find('li.active');
```

Comment: console.log( _this ) ----> []

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use directly as

> $('#js-carousel-menu>li.active');

Answer (score 0):

You are adling The active class to the **second** li element (index 1). So I'm presuming you only add one li which is way you have no li. active